# About the translucent effect of three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a need. I need to make a window. The glass on the window is transparent. I have found some examples:
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_shaders_fresnel
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction

The background of these examples is static pictures.
My background is dynamic. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `THREE.Refractor` like shown in this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_refraction). It allows you to create a refractive see-through surface. You might have to adjust the respective shader program in order to achieve your intended visual result (the default shader of `THREE.Refractor` does not perform any distortions).

Comment: This is a good example!
But I noticed that the refractor is unidirectional. Is there any way to do it in both directions? I'm loading two refractors now.

Comment: You can't do it it both directions right now since an instance of `THREE.Refractor` maintains a virtual camera for rendering the refractive part of the scene. Thus, using a second refractor is necessary.

Comment: thanks.
I found a simpler way:
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( "xxx.png" );
...
mesh.material.map = texture;
mesh.material.transparent = true;
The image is translucent.

Comment: If you don't need refraction, this is actually the easier way.